# Custom log level with LogAdapter in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a Logger object, with a custom log level support (assume TRACE).
I am using LogAdapter to add a contextual information to parameters passed to the logging call.

Since the LogAdapter object is unaware about custom log level function, how should I call it?

```
def get_logger():
    # It will return a logger object which has a custom log level TRACE
    # It will also add a function, trace() in logger for custom level logging

logger = get_logger()
logger2 = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger,{'instance_id':'some random string'})

logger.trace('some log') # It will work
logger2.trace('Some log') # It will not work

# One possible approach to log TRACE level
logger2.log(TRACE,"New trace") # It will work
```